# PHP 7 and Laravel 8 serialize model with private variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-8

I am upgrading a project from PHP 5.4, Laravel 4.2 to PHP 7.4, Laravel 8.

With PHP 5.4 and Laravel 4.2, I would `serialize()` the model with the relations and private variables
to store in redis. When the user has completed their changes, we store to DB and remove from redis.
With PHP 5.4 and Laravel 4.2, using `serialize()` worked great.

With PHP 7.4 and Laravel 8, using `serialize()` does not include the private variables in my model
when serialized. I need to store my model with all relations loaded and private variables in redis
while the user is interacting with the model.

How can make PHP 7.4 and Laravel 8 serialize my model including private variables?

```
class MyParent extends Model
{
  private $privatevalueone = 1;
  private $privatevaluetwo = 2;
  
  public function childeh()
  { return $this->hasOne('ChildEh'); }
  
  public function childbee()
  { return $this->hasMany('ChildBee'); }
  
  public function childsea()
  { return $this->hasMany('ChildSea'); }
  
  // there are a total of 11 relations

  public function calc()
  {
    // - does calculations that can change model properties in relations
    //   and properties in the parent model.
    // - stores values needed while the model is cached using private variables,
    //   the private variables are only needed while cached and not needed when
    //   written to DB
  }

}

/**
 * With PHP 5.4, Laravel 4.2, using serialize preserved
 * the entire model, including private variables in the model
 *
 * With PHP 7.4, Laravel 8, using serialize does not
 * include the private variables in the model,
 */
public function cacheSet($key, $model)
{
  Redis::set($key, serialize($model));
}

public function cacheGet($key)
{
  return unserialize(Redis::get($key));
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php is a good start to accumulate private members as well. Also check with __serialize() magic method https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.serialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the response @nice_dev.
The solution for me was to add the following trait to my model, which does what you referenced to:

```
\Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels
```